# Why was the bounty notice removed by one of the users who answered the question?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

At [Why are some singular masculine attributive adjectives treated like that?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/40790/why-are-some-singular-masculine-attributive-adjectives-treated-like-that/), I started a bounty with a notice saying "authorative reference needed". However, while the bounty is still active, the notice was removed by one of the users who answered the question. I cannot understand why the bounty notice should be removed while the bounty is active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the notice because the text was ... extremely confusing. Not the "authorative reference needed" (which is still visible in the [timeline](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/40790/timeline)); the custom text you wrote in the box. It didn't seem to have something to do with the question at all. Maybe with another one of your questions; I don't remember anymore, and there's no way for me to check or undelete the notice. Moderators can only remove the entire notice, not just the custom text (otherwise I would've done that instead).

Your bounty is still active and the question is still [featured](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/?tab=bounties). The fact that I answered your question doesn't play a role; in fact, I do remember that I only noticed that after removing the bounty notice.